# Javascript alert message Alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my online page I have a simple alert message. I basically need to change the title but I've read that I cannot do that.

Here's the code:

```
<script>alert("My Message Here");</script>
```

In the alert message I get the url of my website and then the message under it.

What is the quickest alternative to having a javascript alert?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use the [jQuery UI dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)?

Comment: [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

Comment: Try googling for javascript modal dialog.

Answer (score 11):

I like this one a lot: http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/

It does not depend on any other JavaScript library and is highly customizable. Supports different kinds of message pop-ups, implements a prompt pop-up and allows message chaining.

Comment: This doesn't support adding HTML at all.  You'll only be able to make messages that are just plaintext, and in which case, if all you get is plaintext, what's the point of adding an entire library for plaintext messages?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger the question was about a quick alternative for a simple JS alert. You will find that in the suggested library. Fair enough if you look for something else.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative is a javascript 'modal window'. Having a google for that should turn up a plethora of options.

This method enables you to style a div however you like and to have that shown in place of the alert box. If you've ever seen a lightbox, the effect and idea is very similar.

They are all very easy to implement. Most often just requiring the inclusion of the script, some CSS and a line of jquery to initialise the modal window on the specific DIV.

Answer (score 3):

If you quickly want to output debugging information, just write it into a div element. For example to write width and height when resizing the window:

```js
    window.onresize = function(event) 
    {
      document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML=window.innerWidth+"x"+window.innerHeight;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <div id="debug">
      Resize your Window to start.
    </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: How is this an alternative to a questionaire context menu?  This is literally just relaying info in plaintext to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done relatively easy, without too much code, and with the feature of fading in/out.  The below example fades in and out at a rate of 3 seconds per fade, but this can be changed by modifying the `fadetime` variable and the `3s` parameter of the CSS definition `transition: opacity 3s;`.

Besides the ability to have fading, the advantage of this answer is that it should be extremely easy to use when making a really customized version.  This solution does not emphasize CSS or styling, I hope it emphasizes the functionality desired.

```js
const fadetime = 3000;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById('message-box-creator').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      document.body.classList.add('disabled-body');
      fadeInElement(document.getElementById('message-box'));
  });
  
  document.getElementById('close-message-box').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    document.body.classList.remove('disabled-body');
    fadeOutElement(document.getElementById('message-box'));
  });
    
            // Fading
            // -------------------------------------------------
    
    function fadeInElement(element) {
        element.style.removeProperty('display');
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.classList.remove('fade');
        }, 10);
        
        return true;
    }
    
    function fadeOutElement(element) {
        element.classList.add('fade');
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }, fadetime);
        
        return true;
    }
});
```

```css
#message-box {
    top:2%;
    
    left:10%;
    width:80%;
    
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:10000;
}

.disabled-body {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.fadeable {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 3s;
}

.fade {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="message-box" class="fadeable fade" style="display:none;">
<b>Note:</b> Message-box has been activated!<br><br>

<button id="close-message-box">Close</button>
</div>

<button id="message-box-creator">Create Alert</button>
</body>
```

Bonus: A function for disabling buttons on the page when doing an alert:

```
function disableAllButtons() {
    const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    
    for (const button of buttons) {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
    
    document.getElementById('close-message-box').disabled = false;
    
    return true;
}
```

Run this function within the event listener for displaying the message (and the reverse for clicking `close`), do the same for `input` and `submit`, and you should have a fully disabled page.