# whats the alternate for alert function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

whats the alternate for alert() function in java script?

I do not want to use the alert function as it will display some message.

I just want to activate a function, when i use alert() the function gets activates and show the result otherwise it doesnt show anything.

Please help!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

(function () {
    var test = document.createElement('script'); 
    test.type = 'text/javascript'; test.async = true;
    test.src = 'http://mysite.com/plugin/myscript.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(test, s);
  alert("hi");

})();

    </script>
```

so the above code runs only if i add alert("hi") in it, otherwise it wont. so how to activate the myscript.js code

Comment: show your alert activating code pls...!

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to accomplish? You want a result, but you don't want it to be shown? Please elaborate.

Comment: First you say you don't want to use it because it will display a message but then you want it to show the result anyway?

Comment: Your function is going to run whether or not the `alert` is in it. Maybe your just think it's not because you're not getting any feedback?

Comment: There is another question that is seeking answers to a similar question, I have an answer there that should help: **[Javascript alert message Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74567397)**

Answer (score 4):

Sure I guess..

```
alert = function(msg) {};
```

Now alert does nothing, and will not display a popup dialogue.

If you wanted to divert any message bound for the `alert` dialogue to your own function, say - a logger - you could do something like this:

```
function log(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  yourOwnFunction(); // You can call and functions if you want.
};

alert = log;
alert("Error!");
```

`"Error!"` now appears in the console log instead of a popup.

**Edit**

All your strings here are **literal** anyway, why don't you just put this before your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/plugin/myscript.js" async="async"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for an alternative for alert()? Try `console.log();`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 window.alert = function(x) {
        // this function executed when you call alert function;
        // x=>message given in alert function
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite `alert` with whatever you want

```
window.alert = function(x) {
    customMessageDialog(x);
};
```

Note that you will not be able to simulate the script-blocking behavior of `alert`, so it might not be safe to replace.

If you just want to do something additional every time an alert is raised, but still use the alert and its blocking qualities, you could do something like this:

```
window.alertOld = window.alert;
window.alert = function(x) {
    customAction(x);
    window.alertOld(x);
};
```

Comment: thanks, but i dont wanna show any custom message, i just want to activate my code. how to do it??

Comment: @Christina: You can replace `customAction(x)` with whatever code you want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use alert in 2012. You have plenty of other options:

1. The browser's console. Try `console.log()`
2. Use a logging framework. [Here is a list](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Javascript_Logging_Frameworks). They usually display a `div` somewhere where the log messages will show up plus plenty of options to filter them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to see the result of a function but don't want to see it as an alert, try `console.log()`, which will show the output in the javascript console

Answer (score 0):

you can use prompt or confirm

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    ...
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(test, s);
    confirm("hi");

    })();

    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let displayedText = '';

// Define div in html a visble div with width and height.
let divForTextToDisplay = document.querySelector('TextDiv');

// Replace with your own loop
function GameLoop() {
  divForTextToDisplay.innerHTML = `${displayedText}`;
}

window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(GameLoop,1000/30);
  blurt('This is an example Text',2000,500)
}


// Extra time is how long the text should stay on screen after completing
function blurt(text, maxTime, extraTime) {
  displayedText = ''
  let induvidualLetterTime = maxTime/text.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      displayedText += text[i];
    }, induvidualLetterTime * i);
 }
 setTimeout(() => {
    displayedText = ''
 }, maxTime + extraTime);
}
```

Displays text in a div (Need to define using HTML and CSS)